# How to get the location of a mobile number using network in android

Tags: android, mobile, gps, location

I need to get the exact latitude and longitude coordinates of a given mobile number in my android app. If I give the mobile number like 9********* i wanted to get the location of where that number is currently located. And have to track the locations wherever the mobile number moves. I googled in all the ways but nothing gives me a solution. Anyone give the idea of doing this

Comment: Check this it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143653/finding-latitude-and-longitude-of-android-mobile-using-its-number

Comment: Its not possible to get mobile number, you can do this with mcc and mnc for a particular device.

Comment: is there any other way to track my friend location? I got the location where the app is opened. But I need to track the locations wherever it goes.

Comment: any example of getting the exact location using mcc and mnc?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Impractical exceptions to the above answer.

- You are a telecommunication company, then you can do triangulation
  between the phone and the nearby cell towers.

  You are law enforcement, then ask the telecommunication company (will
  usually need subpoena).

  You find a way to hack the phone remotely (e.g. using booby trapped
  webpage), and then turn on it's GPS and get it to send back an answer

you can find it for a particular number :

[Find location of mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387354/find-location-of-mobile)